# Multiplying arrays element-wise has unexpected performance in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, task-parallel-library, simd, parallel.for

I want to find the best way to multiply two arrays element-wise. This is one part of a wider project where performance but not the only consideration.

I started writing some functions today in C# (Linqpad) and so it hasn't been optimised in any way. The output from the code below is as follows:

```
Environment.ProcessorCount: 4
Vector<double>.Count: 4

For sequential: 129ms, sum: 2.30619276241231E+25
Plinq: 344ms, sum: 2.30619276241231E+25
Parallel.For: 137ms, 2.30619276241231E+25
Simd sequential: 100ms, sum: 2.30619276241231E+25
Simd parallel: 761ms
```

This consists of the execution time for the multiplication and a sum over the results as a check. There are a few odd results here (and I'm a little rusty in C# so it could well be my code):

- regular for is faster than parallel.for
- plinq is very slow relative to the others - have I done something silly here?
- simd is the fastest but not by much
- intermittently the simd method takes a lot longer
- is parallel simd even possible (bonus points for giving an implementation or explanation)?

My code is as below - there is a reference to the Nuget System.Numerics.Vector package. I'd appreciate any comments, suggestions, corrections or alternatives...

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

void Main()
{
    var random = new Random();

    var arraySize = 20_000_001;

    var x = new double[arraySize];
    var y = new double[arraySize];

    for (var i = 0; i < x.Length; ++i)
    {
        x[i] = random.Next();
        y[i] = random.Next();
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Environment.ProcessorCount: {Environment.ProcessorCount}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Vector<double>.Count: {Vector<double>.Count}\n");

    MultiplyFor(x, y);
    MultiplyPlinq(x, y);
    MultiplyParallelFor(x, y);
    MultiplySIMD(x, y);
    MultiplyParallelSIMD(x, y);

}

void MultiplyPlinq(double[] x, double[] y)
{
    var result = new double[x.Length];

    var sw = new Stopwatch();

    sw.Start();

    result = ParallelEnumerable.Range(0, x.Length).Select(i => x[i] * y[i]).ToArray();

    sw.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine($"Plinq: {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms, sum: {SumCheck(result)}");
}

double SumCheck(double[] x)
{
    return Math.Round(x.Sum() , 4);
}

void MultiplyFor(double[] x, double[] y)
{
    var result = new double[x.Length];

    var sw = new Stopwatch();

    sw.Start();

    for (var i = 0; i < x.Length; ++i)
    {
        result[i] = x[i] * y[i];
    }

    sw.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine($"For sequential: {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms, sum: {SumCheck(result)}");

}

void MultiplyParallelFor(double[] x, double[] y)
{
    var result = new double[x.Length];

    var sw = new Stopwatch();

    sw.Start();

    Parallel.For(0, x.Length, i =>
    {
        result[i] = x[i] * y[i];
    });

    sw.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine($"Parallel.For: {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms, {SumCheck(result)}");

}

void MultiplySIMD(double[] x, double[] y)
{
    var sw = new Stopwatch();

    sw.Start();

    var result = MultiplyByVectors(x, y);

    sw.Stop();

    // 2 cores, 4 logical, 256b register
    Console.WriteLine($"Simd sequential: {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms, sum: {SumCheck(result)}");
}

double[] MultiplyByVectors(double[] x, double[] y)
{
    var result = new double[x.Length];

    var vectorSize = Vector<double>.Count;

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < x.Length - vectorSize; i += vectorSize)
    {
        var vx = new Vector<double>(x, i);
        var vy = new Vector<double>(y, i);
        (vx * vy).CopyTo(result, i);
    }

    for (; i < x.Length; i++)
    {
        result[i] = x[i] * y[i];
    }

    return result;
}

void MultiplyParallelSIMD(double[] x, double[] y)
{
    var sw = new Stopwatch();

    sw.Start();

    var chunkSize = (int)(x.Length / Environment.ProcessorCount);

    Parallel.For(0, Environment.ProcessorCount, i => {

        var complete = i * chunkSize;
        var take = Math.Min(chunkSize, x.Length - i * chunkSize);
        var xSegment = x.Skip((int)complete).Take((int)take);
        var ySegment = y.Skip((int)complete).Take((int)take);
        var result = MultiplyByVectors(xSegment.ToArray(), ySegment.ToArray());

    });

    sw.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine($"Simd parallel: {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");

}
```

Comment: I'd suggest using BenchmarkDotNet, as doing one run per method and timing it with a stopwatch will be very inaccurate and the results could mislead you.
Results:
```
|               Method |      Mean |    Error |    StdDev |
|--------------------- |----------:|---------:|----------:|
|        MultiplyPlinq | 200.29 ms | 5.373 ms | 15.501 ms |
|          MultiplyFor |  87.92 ms | 1.365 ms |  1.276 ms |
|  MultiplyParallelFor |  95.66 ms | 2.835 ms |  8.313 ms |
|         MultiplySIMD |  91.36 ms | 1.463 ms |  1.368 ms |
| MultiplyParallelSIMD | 102.85 ms | 2.770 ms |  7.991 ms |
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`Parallel.For`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for) in its simplest form is not suitable for very granular workloads, because the overhead of invoking an anonymous function on each loop negates the benefits of parallelism (anonymous functions can't be inlined). The solution is to partition the data, so that multiple partitions are processed in parallel, while each partition is processed with a fast direct loop:

```
Parallel.ForEach(Partitioner.Create(0, x.Length), range =>
{
    for (int i = range.Item1; i < range.Item2; i++)
    {
        result[i] = x[i] * y[i];
    }
});
```

The built-in [`Partitioner`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.partitioner) in its [current implementation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/collections/concurrent/PartitionerStatic.cs.html) creates as many partitions as the number of the CPU cores x 3.

Regarding parallelizing SIMD operations, in my own experiments I haven't observed impressive performance improvements in my PC. My theory about it is (and this is just a wild speculation, not an educated guess), that the SIMD calculations are happening so fast that the RAM can't keep up with the rate that the data are crunched by the CPU.

Comment: Yes, if you parallelize with enough cores you can saturate memory bandwidth easily without SIMD, *if* your data isn't already hot in cache.  If it is (especially if the private cache of each core has some data that only that thread needs), then you can get big speedups from SIMD.  Or on a desktop (dual/quad core), a single core can come close to saturating memory bandwidth if you use SIMD, especially for operations like this with 2 read + 1 write stream and only a trivial amount of ALU work.